# Facing issue with telnet.write() in python

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

I Got following code from python documentation, Here I'm not able to write(telnet.write()) after successfully telnet(login) into server.

I have decoded with print statements,please find find details below:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "101.135.93.116"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account login: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")   --> Upto here working fine able to read    **login** 


check = tn.write(user + "\n")
print "checking write --->", check     ----> Here it's printing **None** / Writing nothing here I want user login to be writen

if password:
    verify = tn.read_until("Password: ") 
    print "verify -->" ,verify          ---> able to read **Password**
    padecode = tn.write(password + "\n")
    print "passdecode--->",padecode     ---->  Here it's printing again **None** 


tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()   ------> Not able to read anything not displaying anything
```

Note

If I assume write returns None ,that means it successfully taking credentials then why tn.read_all is not displaying any content ?

Can someone kindly let me know how to write properly after login...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try to put some `sleep` between `check = tn.write(user + "\n")` and 
`print "checking write --->", check`.

Comment: I agree, for telnetting to a lab machine I have I need `time.sleep(64)` before I can move on to issuing a password.  Does it actually login correctly, even if `telnet.write()` returns `None`?

Comment: tried with time.sleep() but still  telnet.write() returning None